# TYPO3 - Tomorrow's date in fluid

Tags: date, format, typo3, fluid

How can I get tomorrow's date in fluid with `f:format.date`?

I need to do an `if` condition in fluid to check if the event's date is earlier than tomorrow.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtotime` strings in `f:format.date`, so you can use `{f:format.date(date: 'tomorrow')}` to get tomorrow's date and compare that to your date. Something like:

```
<f:if condition="{event.date} < {f:format.date(date: 'tomorrow')}">
    <f:then>
        Earlier than tomorrow
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
        Not earlier than tomorrow
    </f:else>
</f:if>
```